# Is there a difference between hosting a server and client on different threads rather than on different processes?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

We have our own networking protocol and my initial integration tests were written to host a Server on one thread and a Client on another thread, then test the communication between those two. However, I was recently told I should use processes to host the Server and Client instead. The reasoning was because of possible synchronization issues and how Java or the OS (don't know which one) handles the scheduling for multithreading.

**Is there actually a difference between running a Server and Client on two threads compared to two processes?**

Comment: Of course - for example `static synchronized` will lock across every thread in the JVM.

Comment: And since they share the same memory and objects, you might have a different behavior compared to isolated processes.

Comment: Ah okay. So then it really is better to write these tests using processes, correct?

Comment: If in real usage they'll always be separate processes, then yes your integration tests better reflect that. But if your server sometimes spawn a client thread in-process, then you want to test that as well.

Comment: when the server and client reside in the same process, they may interact through shared memory, if such interaction is coded in the program. And if it is not coded, then both kind of tests are equivalent.

Comment: I would say this comes down to testing layers - unit tests, single service integration tests, multiple service integration tests, full system integration tests. Ensure you keep the "testing triangle" in mind - the more complex the test setup, the slower and more complex the tests. So I would say have **lots** of tests using an the same process - they'll be fast and easy to write. Have fewer tests with two different processes.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that using processes is better for testing as in a real world scenario, the Client and Server would be on two different processes. As time isn't really an issue, the tests will be thorough and complex.

Thanks again!